# Синхронизация MongoDB и ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, nosql

Здравствуйте,коллеги! Стоит задача переноса коллекции MongoDB в ElasticSearch. Проблема в том, что в коллекции используется Type Discriminator. Кто нибудь знает как сделать маппинг в ES из NEST for c# ?